# Using a column as a column index to extract value from a data frame in R

Tags: r, indexing, extract

I am trying to use the values from a column to extract column numbers in a data frame. My problem is similar to this topic in [r-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-a-column-as-a-column-index/). Copying the script here:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 y = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
                 choice = c("x", "y", "x", "z"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However, instead of having column names in `choice`, I have column index number, such that my data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 y = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
                 choice = c(1, 2, 1, 3),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I tried using this solution:

```
df$newValue <-
  df[cbind(
    seq_len(nrow(df)),
    match(df$choice, colnames(df))
  )]
```

Instead of giving me an output that looks like this:

```
#   x y choice newValue
# 1 1 4   1        1
# 2 2 5   2        2
# 3 3 6   1        6
# 4 8 9   3        NA
```

My `newValue` column returns all NAs.

```
    # x y choice newValue
    # 1 1 4   1        NA
    # 2 2 5   2        NA
    # 3 3 6   1        NA
    # 4 8 9   3        NA
```

What should I modify in the code so that it would read my `choice` column as column index?

Comment: Look at `match(df$choice, colnames(df))` - your columns are not named `"1"` `"2"` etc so `match` doesn't work.

Comment: @thelatemail do you have a suggested workaround?

Comment: Ronak has already got it covered it appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have column numbers which we need to extract from data frame already we don't need `match` here. However, since there is a column called `choice` in the data which you don't want to consider while extracting data we need to turn the values which are not in the range to `NA` before subsetting from the dataframe.

```
mat <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$choice)
mat[mat[, 2] > (ncol(df) -1), ] <- NA 
df$newValue <- df[mat]

df
#  x y choice newValue
#1 1 5      1        1
#2 2 6      2        6
#3 3 7      1        3
#4 4 8      3       NA
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 y = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
                 choice = c(1, 2, 1, 3))
```

Comment: your code takes out the 'newValue' column which is the output and replaces the 'choice' with the value that I expect to be in 'newValue'... the 'choice' column is supposed to be the calling the indices.

Comment: @mand3rd Yes, I messed up the output column name. I have now corrected it, can you check ?

Comment: it did work. can you clarify what this line of code means: 'mat[mat[, 2] > (ncol(df) -1), ] <- NA'

Comment: @mand3rd In `choice` column you have value which is 3 but you want to select values from `df` for only 1st and 2nd column because 3rd column is `choice` column. So in this line `mat[mat[, 2] > (ncol(df) -1), ] <- NA ` we replace all those values which are more than 2 to `NA`.